# Prove that A is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Given $A\subseteq \Bbb R$.Prove that $A$ is closed iff for any $z\in \Bbb R\backslash A$, there exist $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $(z-\epsilon,z+\epsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$

It just seems one is saying the things 'inside' and one is saying the things 'outside'. Any hints for both direction?

Comment: what is your definition of an open set?

Comment: It actually didn't tell anything about open set. It defines closed set as : if A is closed, then  {limit points of A} $\subseteq $ A

Comment: @mathshungry Then, what is your definition of limit points? (It will be easier to help you if we know in which framework you work :) )

Comment: My definition of limit points is that: Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R$.A point $z \in \Bbb R$ is a limit point of A if for any $\delta >0$, there exists a>0 s.t. $0<|z-a|< \delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hints according to your comment:

$\implies\;\;$If $\;A\;$ is closed then it contains all its limit points. Thus, if $\;z\in\Bbb R\setminus A\;$ then $\;z\;$ is **not** a limit point of $\;A\;$ ...

$\;\Longleftarrow\;\;$ If z is a limit point of $\;A\;$ but it is **not** contained in $\;A\;$ then there exists $\;\epsilon>0\;$ s.t. $\;(z-\epsilon,\,z+\epsilon)\cap A=\emptyset\;$ ...but this is a contradiction to the assumption.